# AlertDialog Cannot Resolve Symbol

Tags: java, android

I trying to Add an AlertDialog to my Android App, it show a several "Cannot Resolve Symbol". See the image (The errors marked Red).

[image: Image Here]

**Alert Dialog :**

```
 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: I clicked alt + enter and it fixed but the other still with errors.  http://imgur.com/a/soYYC

Comment: Please stop posting screenshots and instead post some code which actually represents what you are trying to compile. Also, you can post the error messages as text, not screenshots.

Comment: Why is this code outside of onCreate?

Answer (score 4):

That is because you have to put these lines inside a method and call this method.
You can't put the code inside the class like this.

Try doing like this:

```
public void createAlertDialog() {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Alert");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Alert message to be shown");
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

And wherever you want, you can call the method like this:

`createAlertDialog();`

Comment: how can i call it inside a button (XML file)?

Comment: Set a clickListener to your button and call this method inside `onClick` method. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) out

Comment: Quite old, but can someone explain to me what the logic is in this?

Answer (score 4):

You missed importing the relevant packages

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
```